# How to change background image with the help of url parameter in php?

Tags: php, html, css, variables, url-parameters

I'm trying to change background image of a simple php page with help url parameter. I'm very newbie and don't know much coding.

```
<img width="250" src="https://i.imgur.com/<?php echo $_GET['img']; ?>.png">
```

When i use the above code in url i will get desire image from imgur.com by just entering the image link for example:

http://example.com/?img=frotzyG (full image url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2ez8.jpg)

but it just show in a div e.g.

```
<div class="abc">
<img width="250" src="https://i.imgur.com/<?php echo $_GET['img']; ?>.png">
</div>
```

Now i want the same thing to happen for background image. I have a simple php page and its background image source is located in a css (e.g stylesheet.css)

Here's CSS file code:

```
body {
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

How to change background image with the help of url parameter (or whatever you call it.)

P.S. Sorry for my bad English, hope you understand my point.

Answer (score 0):

You might move css related to background image into HTML using style tag.

```
<style>
  body {
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/<?php echo $_GET['img']; ?>.jpg);
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. I have another question now will it automatically pick the other values from CSS file like :

   no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

or i will have to include them between <style> </style>?

Comment: Other values apply from CSS